# How to confirm whether the packages in local mirror are updated and in sync with official repo for ubuntu-20/22

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04, patch-management, ubuntu-22.04, apt-mirror

I have created a local repo using apt-mirror for ubuntu20 and 22. When I run the command apt-mirror the command is successfully run. I see some files like packages.gz is showing the latest timestamp. How can I confirm that the apt-mirror is running and all the latest packages are downloaded successfully to the local repo?

Thanks in Advance!